# Apache2 - Symbolic link not allowed or not accessible

Tags: permissions, apache2, symlink

I have a simple VHost setup, like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName my.server.com

    # SSL setup

    DocumentRoot /srv/www/htdocs/
    HostnameLookups Off
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerSignature Off

    <Directory "/srv/www/htdocs">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and my `/srv/www/htdocs` contains a couple of symlinks, such as `release`. `FollowSymLinks` is enabled, but still, Apache complains with

```
[Sat Sep 21 17:16:26.988517 2019] [core:error] [pid 28117] [client x.x.x.x:39412] AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /srv/www/htdocs/releases
```

This is the output `namei -om /srv/www/htdocs/releases`:

```
f: /srv/www/htdocs/releases
 drwxr-xr-x root    root /
 drwxr-xr-x root    root srv
 drwxr-xr-x root    root www
 drwxr-xr-x jenkins root htdocs
 lrwxrwxrwx root    root releases -> /relstore
   drwxr-xr-x root    root /
   drwxrwxrwx root    root relstore
```

so one can clearly see that the symlink can be resolved and that all directories have world r-x rights. SELinux can be ruled out, as this is disabled (as checked via `getenforce`).

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Apache 2.4.x seems to verify the owner of a symlink by default and this owner must then match the owner of the target of the symlink. To disable this behaviour, specify `-SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` as additional `Options` directive, i.e.

```
<Directory "/srv/www/htdocs">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    ...
</Directory>
```